# How can I install the latest version of Ruby via RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

rvm list known returns the following:

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p598]
[ruby-]2.1.4
[ruby-]2.1[.5]
[ruby-]2.2.0
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head
```

According to the Ruby website, 2.2.1 is the latest version, but I don't see it listed on the rvm list. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

`rvm install ruby-head`

This will compile straight from Ruby's github directory

OR

`rvm install 2.2.1`

Even if isn't listed usually using version number when listed at official website works flawlessly